# Backendless Sorting on Field in Child Table

Tags: java, sql, backendless

Using the Backendless platform, can I sort the query results on a field in a child table.

Lets say I have three (one to many) tables: Authors, Books, and Reviews

Can I get the query results sorted by the Reviews.Updated field

```
List<String> sortBy = new ArrayList<String>();
sortBy.add( "Authors.Books.Reviews.updated DESC" );    
queryOptions.setSortBy( sortBy );
```

https://backendless.com/documentation/data/android/data_sorting.htm

Answer (score 0):

No, sorting is available only on the table where the request is sent to.